# Android Studio 4.2.1 deleting mipmap folders after change my icon?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile, android-studio-4.2

**When i try to change my app icon, Android Studio deleting mipmap folders!!!**

[image]

[image]

**Here are mipmap folders but when I check them i find them empty!**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having a similar problem changing the launcher icon. When I would do a build *some* of the `mipmap` files would be deleted. I found that launcher icons for API 25 and below were affected. On the target system, the default launcher icon was shown rather than my custom icon.

Here's what seemed to work: I used File Explorer to delete all of the `ic_launcher*` files, then used Android Studio to create a new `ic_launcher` Image Asset.  All of the folders were populated and the files stayed in place when I did a build. The launcher icons were correct on all API levels.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and followed the accepted answer , but still rebuilding the files inside `mipmap/ic_launcher*.xml` folder were getting deleted back, later I updated the Android Studio from Dolphin to Electric Eel and It started to work fine